# Create 3d chart with csv with soil data

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

Hello how are you ? As you will see, I am very new to python and I need to make a script which allows me to open csv files and plot them in 3d.
To enter into context, the idea is that the graph is divided into X and Y that would represent the soil measurement sector, so to speak we define that 20 samples will be made in 10 hectares, a grid with 20 tables or plots should be generated where Z would be the measurement itself of each soil product, which are 9, (pH, temperature, humidity, nitrogen, potassium, phosphorus, salinity, tds, electro conductivity).
I think that for a visual question it would be good to see one value at a time and not all together, maybe put check boxes to click which value to see in the graph.

Regarding the order of data, I have thought that it is x, y, val1, val2, val3, val4 etc being the value represented by Z.

I started a code but I can't get it to work with a CSV.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import numpy as np
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import filedialog
#seccion para abrir archivos
root = tk.Tk()
root.withdraw()

file_path = filedialog.askopenfilename()

## PARSEO DE DATA EN EJES
x1, y1, z1 = np.loadtxt(file_path, delimiter=',', unpack=True) #'muestras.txt'

""""
X,Y = np.meshgrid(np.arange(10), np.arange(10))
Z = np.sin(X) + np.sin(Y)
x = X.flatten()
y = Y.flatten()
z = Z.flatten()
"""
X,Y = np.meshgrid(np.arange(10), np.arange(10))
Z = z1
x = x1
y = y1

x = X.flatten()
y = Y.flatten()
z = Z.flatten()

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(9,3.2))
plt.subplots_adjust(0,0.07,1,1,0,0)
ax = fig.add_subplot(121, projection='3d')
ax2 = fig.add_subplot(122, projection='3d')
ax.set_title("trisurf with color acc. to z")
ax2.set_title("surface with color acc. to x")

ax.plot_trisurf(x,y,z ,  cmap="magma")

colors =plt.cm.magma( (X-X.min())/float((X-X.min()).max()) )
ax2.plot_surface(X,Y,Z ,facecolors=colors, linewidth=0, shade=False )

ax.set_xlabel("x")
ax2.set_xlabel("x")
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `np.loadtxt` for loading a CSV file, try installing pandas and use the built in `read_csv()`.

Pandas:
https://pypi.org/project/pandas/

Docs for read_csv:
https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html

Example of reading the csv with pandas:

```
import pandas as pd

dataframe = pd.read_csv(file_path)

# If you want all the data as np array:
np_values = dataframe.values
```